# Thinkpad Tablet 2 Windows 8 Pro Task Scheduler won't do full resume

Tags: windows-8, sleep, scheduled-tasks

I have a problem with the Windows 8 Pro task scheduler on a Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet 2.

Before I begin, the process of which I speak works perfectly on Windows 7 Pro on numerous laptops, older tablets, and desktops.

Scenario:

1. I have an application that runs continuously on the TPT2 and is intended to wake up periodically to notify a family member with medical issues.
2. I have created a Task Scheduler script (identical to the one which works on Windows 7) that starts the computer at scheduled times.
3. I set the TPT2 to "sleep" in its terms, that is, the TPT2 has no S1, S2, or S3 state, only S4 which is 'connected sleep (a new "feature").
4. I only use the real Windows desktop on the TPT2 and nothing in Metro is part of this scenario.

What I have observed:

1. As long as the TPT2 is put into S4, the Task Scheduler starts a "do nothing" program  but unlike Windows 7, this does not resume the TPT2 as the power button does. It only runs the program which includes putting up a MessageBox which doesn't appear.

   a. The display stays dark

   b. No "resume" Windows Form message is sent to all active forms applications.
2. If I hibernate the TPT2, the scheduled task is not run at the scheduled time but only when I manually resume the system by pressing the power button.
3. Since the power options on the TPT2 don't include things like wake=up timers, I had to delve into the registry and into the powercfg -QH to determine that they or their equivalent are available as evidenced by the fact that the scheduled task runs but only from S4.
4. Third party task schedulers don't run as they can't find the hardware wake timers.

So with all of that, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to fully resume the Win 8 Pro TPT2 from the task scheduler just like the resume button does and like the Windows 7 does?
2. What is the command-line command to put the Win 8 Pro TPT2 into S4 'connected sleep'?

Regards,
Jim